# Find each checked radio button value on separate forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now, I am storing two forms full of radiobuttons in separate div tags.

I need to be able to compare the checked radiobuttons from the left and right div tag.

Right now, I have this code to look for the checked values in the right and left div tags, however; it's checking the left div tag radiobutton values twice.

```
   $('#btn').click(function() {
        $("#right input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {
            var idVal = $(this).attr("id");
            var rightcity = ($("label[for='"+idVal+"']").text());
            console.log(rightcity);
            $('#rightcity').text(rightcity);
        });
        $("#left input[type='radio']:checked").each(function() {
            var idVal = $(this).attr("id");
            var leftcity = ($("label[for='"+idVal+"']").text());
            console.log(leftcity);
            $('#leftcity').text(leftcity);
        });

        });
```

Any idea on how to specifically run this query for the right div tag values as well?

Comment: Can you also post the html and do you have all the radio buttons with same name in the left div and a same name for the radio buttons in the right div?

Comment: You just want to get all the checked radio buttons in a single shot and run the each function? `$("#right input[type='radio']:checked, #left input[type='radio']:checked")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st : if radios with same group in left/right . no need to loop through

2nd you can try this

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
            var rightId = $("#right input[type='radio']:checked").attr("id");
            var leftId = $("#left input[type='radio']:checked").attr("id");
            var rightcity = $("label[for='"+rightId+"']").text();
            var leftcity =  $("label[for='"+leftId+"']").text();

            console.log(rightcity);
            $('#rightcity').text(rightcity);
            console.log(leftcity);
            $('#leftcity').text(leftcity);

});
```

maybe you don't need to get ids .. if your html

```
<label></label>
<input type="radio"/>
```

you can directly use .prev()  instead of getting ids

```
var rightcity = $("#right input[type='radio']:checked").prev('label').text();
var leftcity = $("#left input[type='radio']:checked").prev('label').text();
```

and if its

```
<input type="radio"/>
<label></label>
```

use .next()

```
 var rightcity = $("#right input[type='radio']:checked").next('label').text();
 var leftcity = $("#left input[type='radio']:checked").next('label').text();
```

and about *(be able to compare the checked radiobuttons from the left and right div tag)*

```
var rightValue = $("#right input[type='radio']:checked").val();
var leftValue = $("#left input[type='radio']:checked").val();
```